# NotifyDataSetChanged() not refreshing list?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, baseadapter

I know this question has been asked thousands of times but I couldn't find an answer for my case for some reason.

What I have is a thread that fetches data from a web services and populates a list with the info. Then I want to press a button and call the same thread to fetch some more data and add it to the list.

But when I call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, the list for some reason doesn't refresh. The data is in the adapter though...

Here's the code:

```
    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(PropertyNotesParser result) {

            this.progressDialog.dismiss();

            ArrayList<PropertyNoteHistory> propertyNoteList = result.getAllTheNotes();
            addNoteListItems(propertyNoteList);

            Collections.sort(getNoteList());

            ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> subtitles = new ArrayList<String>();
            DateHandler handleDate = new DateHandler();
            DataResolve convert = new DataResolve();

            for(Iterator<PropertyNoteHistory> i = getNoteList().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                PropertyNoteHistory item = i.next();

                PropertyNoteHistory.Note note = item.getNotes();
                PropertyNoteHistory.Jobs jobs = item.getJobs();

                // Default value is office in case the xml does not have the tag "job" associated with "note".
                String service = "Office";

                if(jobs != null){
                    service = convert.getServiceName(jobs.getServiceID());
                } 

                titles.add(note.getTitle() + " (" + service + ")");
                subtitles.add(handleDate.formatDate(note.getDate(), "dd MMM yyyy") + " Ref: " + note.getJobID());
            }

            if(getConnectionCount() == 0){
                adapter = new SimpleListAdapter(getActivity(), titles, subtitles);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            else {
                adapter.addItem(titles, subtitles);

            }
```

and my adapter:

```
    public class SimpleListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private int count = 0;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> subtitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> imageResource = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private boolean hasImage = false;

    public SimpleListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> titles,
            ArrayList<String> subtitles, ArrayList<Integer> imageResource) {
        count = titles.size();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.titles = titles;
        this.subtitles = subtitles;
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
        this.hasImage = true;
    }

    /**Constructor that creates an adapter with only a title and subtitle.
     * @param activity The context.
     * @param titles ArrayList with the titles of each list option.
     * @param subtitles ArrayList with the subtitles of each list option. */
    public SimpleListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> titles,
            ArrayList<String> subtitles) {
        count = titles.size();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.titles = titles;
        this.subtitles = subtitles;
        this.hasImage = false;
    }

    public void addItem(ArrayList<String> title, ArrayList<String> subtitle){
        this.titles.addAll(title);
        this.subtitles.addAll(subtitle);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if(v == null)
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_simple_list, null);
        final ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        final TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        final TextView subtitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

        title.setText(titles.get(position));
        subtitle.setText(subtitles.get(position));
        if (hasImage) {
            icon.setImageResource(imageResource.get(position));
        }

        else {
            icon.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
        }

        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: you are not updating the `count` value in addItem

Comment: where are you notifying data set changed by the way ?

Comment: what @njzk2 said, or just use `return titles.size()` in `getCount()` instead

Comment: Very well spotted. I'm trying right now.

Comment: Give that man a medal! Thanks @njzk2. Im new to SO so... how do I set it as the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update your `count` variable too in `addItem` so that the all the rows are created when `notifyDataSetChanged` is called

Comment: int currentCount = getConnectionCount();
    setConnectionCount(currentCount + 1);

    getAndParseNotes(lvPropertyNotes); --> getAndParseNotes() calls the Thread...

Comment: Is it being called before `notifyDataSetChanged`?

Comment: @VancertStaff Apoorv said to update the count variable in your Adapter class, not connection count... override getCount() method of Adapter like this `@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }`

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Thought he was talking about the connectionCount. noob mistake :P Answer accepted.